# Calling JS function after BIND?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm building a ColdFusion 10 form, similar to an invoice. It contains three columns.

The first column is a filter to select a subset of all available products: it contains cfselect that are built from a query of product categories.

The second column is the product itself: it contains cfselect that are BINDed to a table containing a product list, only showing the products from the matching category.

The third column is the product price: it contains cfdiv that are BINDed to the product prices, in the same table.

I'm looking for a way to compute the total price (sum) of the selected items. I'm especially looking for the "something has changed" trigger to attach to.

Solutions that I see:

- the total is another BIND, depending on the price on each item. A bit ugly, since this would be done server-side, even if a simple JS could do it.
- use onChange on the cfselect. In that case, how can I ensure that the price BIND have been performed before the total is computed?
- use onChange on the cfselect, and directly query the prices in that script (i.e. remove the BIND on the price columns) with XMLHttpRequest. I wrote some code to do this and it seems to work, but I still need to change it to asynchronous requests, and decode the return in an browser-independent way. This seems way more complex than needed.
- use a (non-existing) onChange on the cfdiv. This would be the easiest... but that hook doesn't exist.
- use a cfselect/cfinput instead of the cfdiv in the third column, and cheat with css to make it look like a div. Ugly.
- same as previous, but hidden, and keep the existing cfdiv visible. Probably the best bet right now, but all queries will be performed twice. I'm sure there's a better way.
- use a timer. I'd rather avoid that.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is to stop using any of the ColdFusion UI wizards - which are very poorly implemented - and just use HTML & JS (the JS via one of the popular libraries). That way you'd not be fighting the limitations and poor, outdated quality of CF's UI-centric features.  Just use JQuery or something.

Comment: I disagree.  I equate that to wheel re-inventing.

Comment: What exactly is in the 3rd column (the div)?

Comment: @DanBracuk it is not re-inventing the wheel...it is more akin to not using a re-invention of the wheel - a poorly implemented, over architected, re-invention at that. jmr - stop using cfform and cfselect and cfdiv, do as Adam notes and learn how to do thing the real/right way. Otherwise you are simply handicapping (and pigeon holing) yourself.

Comment: @DanBracuk, Scott's hit the nail on the head. There are far better/faster wheels out there than ColdFusion's UI widgets.

Comment: @DanBracuk: just edited the question, trying to address your question

Comment: All: thanks for your feedback. but I must say that from here, they look a bit ideological, and not that helpful in the short term.

Comment: Don't describe code - show the code. Also, heed what Adam and Scott are saying. Even if you don't ditch the _badly implemented_ CF UI stuff immediately, you can probably still switch to jQuery/similar and use it against the generated HTML.

Comment: @jmr our suggestions may not be helpful in the short term, but in the long term, you will thank us. Learn how to do things the right/real way and not use ColdFusion as a crutch when it comes to UI and AJAX.

Comment: They're not ideological, they're sound, practical advice. Probably not what you want to hear, but this doesn't make it any the less sound.

Comment: All: again, thanks for taking the time to read the question and contribute to it. I really appreciate it (and as you can see, I ended up using jQuery). But I maintain my position that something a little bit more detailed than "ditch CF and use jQuery or something else" would have helped. As an analogy, if someone asks you some help to remove a virus from his Windows machine and your answer is "wipe your hard drive and install Linux", you might be right and helping him in the long term... but that won't fix the immediate issue. Sorry for the rant, it's been a long week.

Comment: This seems to be coming up a lot lately and I recently found a pretty good blog about it from Ben Forta. Read this - http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense. Make sure you read it because the title is a bit mis-leading.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, in case it can helps someone else.

What I had trouble finding and that this example may illustrate

- rough jQuery equivalent of simple CF BIND
- example of $.get() that actually do someting with the downloaded data, not just alert() it

$.get() definitely isn't the recommended way to get introduced to jQuery.

This will probably make the "pros" shout in horror. It shouldn't be considered copy-paste code, only hints on figuring a way to do it.

It actually has been strongly edited from my working version, so it may contain dummy typos.

OK, enough disclaimers.

```
function dollarize (price) {
    // unrelated code - just ensure that the price is always displayed with two decimals
}

function downloadPrice(url, DOM_Item_ID) {
    $.get( url,
           function(data,status){           // keep in mind that this function is called ASYNCHRONOUSLY
                //alert(data);  // typical data received, for a $1 item:  <wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>1</string></data></wddxPacket>
                var payload = $(data).find('string').text();
                $('##' + DOM_Item_ID).text('$' + dollarize(parseFloat(payload)));   <!--- normally a single # - doubled since in a <cfoutput> --->
                UpdateTotalPrice();
          },
          "xml");
}

function UpdateTotalPrice() {
    var price = 0;
    for(var e=1;e<=#MAX_NUMBER_ITEM#;e++)
    {
        var node = document.getElementById("Item_"+e);
        var ID = node.selectedIndex;
        if(ID != 0) {
            prix += parseFloat(document.getElementById("Price_"+e).childNodes[0].nodeValue.substring(1));       // substring(1): removes the $ added above
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('TotalPrice').childNodes[0].nodeValue = '$' + dollarize(prix);
}

function onChangeItem(e) {
    var ID = document.getElementById("Item_"+e).value;
    downloadPrice("#application.CFC_PATH#gestion-equipements.cfc?method=trouvePrixStandardEquipement&ID="+ID,
            "Price_"+e);
}
```

2nd column:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#MAX_NUMBER_ITEM#" index="e">
    ...
        <cfselect Name="Item_#e#" ID="Item_#e#" bind="........." bindonload="yes" queryPosition="below" onChange="onChangeItem(#e#)"><option value="0">--</cfselect>
```

Each price item in the 3rd column:

```
<cfdiv ID="Price_#e#" align="right">$0.00</cfdiv>       <!--- content of the div (i.e. $0.00) must NOT be empty, otherwise childNodes[0] above will fail --->
```

Total price:

```
<cfdiv ID="TotalPrice">$0.00</cfdiv>
```